# Does "code" make a good tag or not?

Tags: discussion, tags

Most questions on the Main site appear to fall into two categories, those solved through the UI and those solved though coding.  We have tags for Drupal 6 or Drupal 7 and other broader categories so a tag to identify code vs. UI questions seemed like a good idea. Then I found the 'Code' tag with a description to avoid using it.  What is the Stack Exchange thinking/policy regarding this type of tag?

Answer (score 5):

When a tag can be used for almost all the questions, that tag stops to be useful. Tags should be used to categorize questions, but if a tag is used in all the questions, in which way does it help to categorize? To make an example, it would be like using [drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/drupal) for questions asked on Drupal Answers.

A simple test to check when a tag can be useful is to verify it can be used alone. Does using [code](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code) alone help understanding what kind of question is being asked? It just makes me understand the question is about code, but it doesn't help in understanding which type of code. Differently, [nodes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nodes) makes you understand the question is about nodes, and [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) is a question about the Views module, or a view created with that module.

Comment: I see the point, but let me point out that the first tag found for this post was 'discussion', also a bit broad, but useful :)

Comment: Tags on meta sites are different. In particular, [meta-tag:bug], [meta-tag:discussion], and [meta-tag:support] are tags that must be used for every question asked on a meta site; this means that every questions asked on meta needs at least one of those tags, which are not used on the main site.

Comment: +1; a question might involve code, but it could hardly be said to be *about* code, unless the subject was Drupal coding methodologies or some such. Even if a problem was related to a chunk of code, that's no way to categorize it for searching/subscribing.

Comment: And indeed, if the question _is_ about code, there are already appropriate tags for specific topics like [php], [javascript] and [css] etc.

Comment: +1 for the code. There could be two types of questions in the Drupal Answers, one is related to code and another is related to Admin UI.